# Regex to remove certain text when matched

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to do some operations on a text using regex.

The text I am working on is below:

```
text="abcd<table class='navbox-columns-table'>The seating</tr>\n</table>fghi<table class='navbox-columns-table'>Going Down</tr>\n</table>"
```

I want to remove all the text that matches the regex

```
<table class=.+?>(.+?)</table>
```

I am trying to achieve this using re.sub

```
re.sub(r'<table class=.+?>(.+?)</table>', '1234', text)
```

I dont get the required output.

The output I need is :

```
"abcdfghi"
```

The regex seems to be correct becasue I get proper output when I do a findall()

```
re.findall('<table class=.+?>(.+?)</table>', text, re.DOTALL)

Output: ['The seating</tr>\n', 'Going Down</tr>\n']
```

Comment: Your regex have a mistake at `/` should be escaped `\/`

Comment: @AvinashRaj: oups, python regex ... no need to escape :D thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include DOTALL modifier `(?s)`, so that it would make dot present in your regex to match line breaks.

```
>>> text="abcd<table class='navbox-columns-table'>The seating</tr>\n</table>fghi<table class='navbox-columns-table'>Going Down</tr>\n</table>"
>>> re.sub(r'(?s)<table class=.+?>(.+?)</table>', '', text)
'abcdfghi'
```

Comment: want 1234 instead of empty string then use `re.sub(r'(?s)<table class=.+?>(.+?)</table>', '1234', text)`

Comment: Hi Avinash, Thanks for the reply. It works fine now. However, I even tried using re.DOTALL.  Something like ......  re.sub(r'<table class=.+?>(.+?)</table>', '1234', text,re.DOTALL) .......Is it different from what you suggested.

Comment: no, both are same. I wrote `(?s)` because it's simpler than `re.DOTALL`

Comment: But --re.sub(r'<table class=.+?>(.+?)</table>', '', text, re.DOTALL) doesn't work.  But you expression works perfectly.

Comment: try You need to specify `flags` `re.sub(r'<table class=.+?>(.+?)</table>', '1234', text, flags=re.DOTALL)`

Answer (score -1):

```
re.sub(r"(?s)<table[^>]*class=\'.+?\'[^>]*>.*?</table>", r"", string)
```